# How to turn convert rows to columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert every three rows of a `DataFrame` into columns .

`Input:`

```
import pandas as pd  
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,11,12,13],'b':['a','b','c','aa','bb','cc']})
print(df)
```

`Output:`

```
    a   b
0   1   a
1   2   b
2   3   c
3  11  aa
4  12  bb
5  13  cc
```

`Expected:`

```
   a1  a2  a3  b1  b2  b3
0   1   2   3   a   b   c
1  11  12  13  aa  bb  cc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by floor division and modulo by `3` with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and flattening `MultiIndex`:

```
a = np.arange(len(df))
#if default index
#a = df.index
df1 = df.set_index([a // 3, a % 3]).unstack()
#python 3.6+ solution
df1.columns = [f'{i}{j + 1}' for i,j in df1.columns]
#python bellow 3.6
#df1.columns = ['{}{}'.format(i,j+1) for i,j in df1.columns]
print (df1)
   a1  a2  a3  b1  b2  b3
0   1   2   3   a   b   c
1  11  12  13  aa  bb  cc
```

Comment: Hey, do you know why `df.set_index(np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]))` works as expected but `df.set_index([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])` throws a `KeyError`?

Comment: @timgeb - Yes, there is simpliest explain it with list - If assign `df.set_index([0,1])` is means set columns `0,1` to MultiIndex, but if use `df.set_index([[0,1]])` it means create index from list `0,1`. and `df.set_index(np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]))` working like `df.set_index([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])`

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding a different approach with `group` -> `apply`.

`df` is first grouped by `df.index//3` and then the `munge` function is applied to each group.

```
def munge(group):
    g = group.T.stack()
    g.index = ['{}{}'.format(c, i+1) for i, (c, _) in enumerate(g.index)]
    return g

result = df.groupby(df.index//3).apply(munge)
```

Output:

```
>>> df.groupby(df.index//3).apply(munge)
   a1  a2  a3  b4  b5  b6
0   1   2   3   a   b   c
1  11  12  13  aa  bb  cc
```